# Does not save html select data from ajax query to session

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, select

I'm creating a form where the users have to select their country and city from a select field, which is dynamically updated corresponding to the actual country selected. However when the form is submitted everything is getting saved successfully except the city.

I'm using jquery select2 and jquery validation plugin, I think those could cause the problem.

Here is the main code:

```
$('#country').select2().change(function() {
                $("#city").select2('data', null);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'search_city.php',
                    data: 'country=' + $(this).val(),
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function(response) {
                        $('#city').html(response);
                    }
                });
            });
```

and

```
<label>* City:</label>
    <select id="city" name="property_city" required>
        <option></option>
    </select>
```

and this is search_city.php

```
echo '<option></option>';
while($city = mysqli_fetch_object($cities)) {
    if($_SESSION['property_city'] == $city->id) {
        echo '<option selected value="'.$city->id.'">'.$city->name.'</option>';                                                                 
    } else {
        echo '<option value="'.$city->id.'">'.$city->name.'</option>';
    }
}
```

When the form is submitted a validation php runs where I save the data to session variables. There are more inputs, not just the country and the city, and they are saved successfully except the city I mentioned.

I can't figure out what the problem is. I did't include all the code, maybe something else could cause the problem, however if someone could find it here I would be relieved.

Comment: Can you paste the code of how you are saving the values?

Comment: I start the sessions in the file which contains the form and save the data in another validation php file like this:
$_SESSION['property_city'] = $_POST['property_city'];

Comment: I meant you said the city is not getting saved into the database? So the code of that.

Comment: I don't save the data to database yet. It is in sessions right now. Saving to database will be the last step.

Comment: Can you post the full code of search_city.php?

Comment: Well except the mysql connection, which I wouldn't write here there is only one row that I didn't mention:
$countryId = $_POST['country'];

Answer (score 0):

You need to write,

```
$html =  '<option value=""></option>';
while($city = mysqli_fetch_object($cities)) {
    if($_SESSION['property_city'] == $city->id) {
        $html .= '<option selected value="'.$city->id.'">'.$city->name.'</option>';                                                                 
    } else {
        $html .= '<option value="'.$city->id.'">'.$city->name.'</option>';
    }
}
echo $html;
```

Comment: Tried adding value="" to the first option, but it didn't solve the problem. Now I'm starting to think it's something with the select2 plugin.